# Fresh restart of PC, now OS gone, how to reinstall using USB

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, reinstall

Recently my computer has been running very slowly (for no apparent reason, as all my hardware, software, drivers, etc... are up to date and functional...) Anyway, I did a complete restart, meaning I erased every file my computer has ever stored in order to start fresh and hopefully solve these performance issues. However, now when I boot up my computer I am greeted with the message, "An operating system wasn't found..." So, I hopped on my Mac and downloaded Windows 10 onto a flash drive, which I then plugged into my PC. However, nothing has changed. After researching some on the Internet, I found [Looking to install Windows 10 on your PC?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/), which told me to "press any key to boot from the USB flash drive". This did not work, and now I am here to ask you geniuses the same thing I asked Google... How do I make this work? What steps do I need to take?

Recap:

- Fresh Restart of PC (No OS, no files, no nothing).
- Downloaded Windows 10 from Mac onto USB.
- Plugged USB into PC.
- Nothing's happening!!

Comment: Download Windows 10 ISO, create UEFI compatible installation media, install Windows 10.  In the future use the Refresh feature instead of doing what you did

Answer (score -1):

On osx we have a solution called - [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/), just select your flash drive and iso image and press ok, but  some pc hardware cant use that bootloader.

I'm always using Virtual PC with any windows (or another PC) for making Windows install flash. U need software called [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and Windows .iso image. Rufus can write install flash for any bootloader - BIOS (legacy) or UEFI (new pc's).

P.S. after making your flash, don't forget hit bios and select proper boot device ;)

Comment: Well I got to the installation screen, but I'm stuck at "Select the driver to install." Its says that it couldn't find a driver for windows 10. I tried restarting and trying both home and pro editions. I would have thought that any drivers for windows 10 would have been installed with the windows 10 download...

Answer (score -1):

The USB/Disk you insert to install an operating system should be bootable i.e. the BIOS should be able to find the file on your USB/Disk and initiate the boot.

It may have happened that the USB your prepared is not bootable.

Here are the steps to follow:

1. Make a bootable USB of Windows from the ISO using a program "Boot Camp Assistant" on mac. Follow the guide here: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-installer-usb-drive-mac
2. Insert USB in your PC and start it.

   - If you see 'press any key to boot from USB" then, press any key and windows installer will load.
   - If you don't see it, Go to your system BIOS settings, and change the order of boot devices. Keep USB at the top. -> Save changes and restart.

Now, to follow the instructions/steps on screen and windows will guide your throughout the installation process.

Comment: Well I got to the installation screen, but I'm stuck at "Select the driver to install." Its says that it couldn't find a driver for windows 10. I tried restarting and trying both home and pro editions. I would have thought that any drivers for windows 10 would have been installed with the windows 10 download...

Comment: Usually the driver problem occurs when you use USB 3.0 port. Try inserting the USB in a USB 2.0 port.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to faff with boot camp, it's a total waste of time. Just take the files from the root of the windows 10 ISO and copy them to a formatted Fat32 USB disk with an Mbr partition and then run the following:

D:\boot\bootsect /nt60 F:

Where D is your ISO and F is the USB drive replace drive letters as apt - if using a Mac and bash you'll have to tweak this but it will be the same principle copy

That command makes a USB drive with windows files on it boot.